# Generating regular expression in Excel for strings

Tags: excel, vba

I have a huge list of strings where the I am trying to generate a regular expression in an automated way. The strings are pretty simple and I would like to generate regular expressions using a formula or vba code. From the list of strings, here is the following legend:

```
& - Any UPPERCASE character (A-Z)
# - Any digits (0-9)
_ - Space (/s)
- - Dash
```

For example, the regular expression generated for the following strings:

```
Policy Number                               Policy Digits   Regular Expression
####&&######                                12              ^\d{4}[A-Z]{2}\d{6}$
####&_######                                11              ^\d{4}[A-Z]{1}\s\d{6}$
ACPBP&&##########                           17              ^[ACPBP]{5}[A-Z]{2}\d{10}$
ACPBA&########## or ACPBA&&##########       16 or 17        ^[ACPBA]{5}[A-Z]{1,2}\d{10}$
##########                                  10              ^\d{10}$
09############                              14              ^[09]{2}\d{12}$
A&&######, A&&#######, or A&&########       9, 10 or 11     ^[A]{1}[A-Z]{2}\d{6,8}$
&&&####, &&&#####, or &&&######             7, 8, or 9      ^[A-Z]{3}\d{4,6}$
09-##########-##                            14              ^[09]{2}-\d{10}-\d{2}$
```

Is there some existing code that is available to generate regular expressions for a huge list of strings? What are some of the hints or tips that I can use to build a regular expression string? Thanks in advance.

Comment: So the input should be the policy number pattern in format above and the output should be the `Regex` pattern ??

Comment: You could do single characters rather than grouping. EG Replace `#` with a `\d` only.

Comment: @Gary'sStudent That's correct

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no existing code, but try this:

```
Option Explicit
Option Compare Text 'to handle upper and lower case "or"
'Set reference to Microsoft Scripting Runtime
'  or use Late Binding if distributing this
Function createRePattern(sPolicyNum As String) As String
    Dim dCode As Dictionary, dReg As Dictionary
    Dim I As Long, sReg As String, s As String
    Dim v, sPN
    
v = Replace(sPolicyNum, "or", ",")
v = Split(v, ",")

Set dCode = New Dictionary
    dCode.Add Key:="&", Item:="[A-Z]"
    dCode.Add Key:="#", Item:="\d"
    dCode.Add Key:="_", Item:="\s"
    
For Each sPN In v
sPN = Trim(sPN)
If Not sPN = "" Then

Set dReg = New Dictionary
For I = 1 To Len(sPN)
    s = Mid(sPN, I, 1)
    If Not dCode.Exists(s) Then dCode.Add s, s
    If dReg.Exists(s) Then
        dReg(s) = dReg(s) + 1
    Else
        If dReg.Count = 1 Then
            dReg.Add s, 1
            s = Mid(sPN, I - 1, 1)
            sReg = sReg & dCode(s) & IIf(dReg(s) > 1, "{" & dReg(s) & "}", "")
            dReg.Remove s
        Else
            dReg.Add s, 1
        End If
    End If
Next I

'Last Entry in Regex
s = Right(sPN, 1)
sReg = sReg & dCode(s) & IIf(dReg(s) > 1, "{" & dReg(s) & "}", "") & "|"

End If
Next sPN

s = Left(sReg, Len(sReg) - 1)

'Non-capturing group added if alternation present
If InStr(s, "|") = 0 Then
    sReg = "^" & s & "$"
Else
    sReg = "^(?:" & Left(sReg, Len(sReg) - 1) & ")$"
End If

createRePattern = sReg

End Function
```

---

### Note

As written, there are limitations in that you cannot reference the literal strings:

`#`, `&`, `_`, `,` `or`

[image]

Comment: Wow!! this looks great. I would like to know if it is necessary to put the "?:" in a regular expression. what is the purpose of that?

Comment: @CrazyCoder Grouping of the matches is only  **required** when there are alternative matches, else the `^` would only apply to the first, and the `$` only to the last.  But it doesn't hurt in the other instances, and was simpler to code that way.  You could certainly modify the code to test for alternation, and only add the Group if there was.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld I noticed an error: I have an input string like this: USF####### or USG####### or USP####### or GLS######## or GLS########&
 and for which your code gave me this regular expression: ^(?:USF\d{7}|USG\d{7}|USP\d{7}|GLS\d{8}|GLS\d{8}\d#)$

When I tested the regular expression for GLS########&, it didn't work. I do notice that the there is an error at the end of regex which says GLS\d{8}#

Comment: @CrazyCoder Thanks for finding that.  There was an error in how it processed the code for the final character, such that if the final character did not repeat, it was causing that error. (It was actually looking at the next-too-last character.  I've edited the code and it seems to be working, but please post back if there are any further issues.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld That works well. Thanks for the quick resolution. I did notice something strange tho. When I copy a long regular expression for a long input string and paste it, i noticed that it is enclosed in double quotes and a space inside the regular expression. I am not sure if that is on my side or the code.

Comment: @CrazyCoder There are no extraneous surrounding quotation marks nor spaces returned by the code.

Answer (score 1):

**Generate regex patterns without dictionary**

- In addition to Ron's valid solution an alternative using no dictionary:

```
Option Explicit                             ' declaration head of code module
Function generateRePattern(ByVal s As String) As String
'[0]definitions & declarations
    Const Pipe As String = "|"
    Dim curSymbol$:    curSymbol = ""       ' current symbol (start value)
    Dim lngth As Long: lngth = Len(s)       ' current string length
    Dim ii    As Long: ii = 0               ' group index    (start value)
    Dim n     As Long                       ' repetition counter
    ReDim tmp(1 To lngth)                   ' provide for sufficient temp items

'[1](optional) Pipe replacement for "or" and commas
    s = Replace(Replace(Replace(s, " or ", Pipe), " ", ""), ",", Pipe)
'[2]analyze string item s
    Dim pos   As Long                       ' current character position
    For pos = 1 To lngth                    ' check each character
        Dim curChar   As String
        curChar = Mid(s, pos, 1)            ' define current character
        If curChar <> curSymbol Then        ' start new group
            'a) change repetition counter in old group pattern
            If ii > 0 Then tmp(ii) = Replace(tmp(ii), "n", n)
            'b) increment group counter & get pattern via help function
            ii = ii + 1: tmp(ii) = getPattern(curChar)     ' << getPattern
            'c) start new repetition counter & group symbol
            n = 1: curSymbol = curChar
        Else
            n = n + 1                       ' increment current repetition counter
        End If
    Next pos
    'd) change last repetition counter
    tmp(ii) = Replace(tmp(ii), "n", n)
    ReDim Preserve tmp(1 To ii)             '

'[3]return function result
    generateRePattern = "^(?:" & Replace(Join(tmp, ""), "{1}", "") & ")$"
End Function
```

**Help function `getPattern()`**

```
Function getPattern(curChar) As String
'Purpose: return general pattern based on current character
'a) definitions
    Const Pipe As String = "|"
    Dim symbols:   symbols = Split("&|#|_", Pipe)
    Dim patterns:  patterns = Split("[A-Z]{n}|\d{n}|\s", Pipe)
'b) match character position within symbols
    Dim pos: pos = Application.Match(curChar, symbols, 0)
'c) return pattern
    If IsError(pos) Then
        getPattern = curChar
    Else
        getPattern = patterns(pos - 1)
    End If
End Function
```